# Design pattern to simplify interface with single methods for each child class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm currently working in a codebase where I see this pattern being repeated again and again which doesn't seems right to me.

There's a single base interface or class with N methods, while having upto N child classes which override one or two of those methods at most. The rest of those methods are overridden and a return null is placed there.

An example would be(cannot disclose original code for obvious reasons) -

```
interface DealService{
  getDealData() 
  getDealRestrictions() 
  getDealRegister() 
  ... 
}
```

Now 1st child class only overrides getDealData with actual implementation and simply returns null for rest of the methods.
2nd child class overrides maybe 2 methods but returns null for all other.

I don't understand why this has been written this way and I want to ask what would've been correct pattern to design such class.

I should mention that the child class objects are definitely kept in list of the parent interface but still there should be some other way to achieve the same?

I tried to search the same pattern across the internet and on several AI tools but could not find satisfactory answer

Comment: I haven't seen such pattern, just wondering - how methods are called? ie if you need deal data, how do they know which instance to call to get data?

Comment: This could be bad design; I would ask around why is this implemented this way, there may be a good reason for it after all. Even if there is a good reason, a requirement, there could be a better way to fulfill this requirement; or not! This could be an interesting problem, but I think we need some more information to help. Can you include e.g. a more specific use case?

Comment: @IłyaBursov they have a map of enum(string name of particular dealService derivation class) and they call it manually(non generically). It's not possible to determine from just code which one should be called apart from checking if the method you want is null in all other siblings.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos apparently this code was written by freshers few years back and no one is in the organization as of today. I can't add specific use case even though I want to as instructed by my seniors. However the only thing current seniors can see is, the number of functions in base interface is too large - 24 so original authors might wanted to break it. But again, current seniors note that it's still very weird.

Comment: then it looks like incorrect implementation of service locator for dependency injection, better either implement it correctly or use DI

Comment: "I should mention that the child class objects are definitely kept in list of the parent interface" What does that mean?

Comment: @laskquestioncozinew This smells more and more like bad design then :) If neither you nor the seniors can find any reason to support this design, then you should probably move away. I can only offer generic advise given the lack of details... decide where you want to go (DI as Ilya Bursov writes is a viable goal... ensure that any goal you set is specific and appropriate for your case though)... write tests... proceed with small, stepwise changes... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> Now 1st child class only overrides getDealData with actual implementation and simply returns null for rest of the methods. 2nd child class overrides maybe 2 methods but returns null for all other.

It looks like [interface segregation principle is violated](https://dev.to/fabriziobagala/interface-segregation-principle-452m) here. What I mean is that if some methods are not necessary to implement or they return `null` then it can be the sign of violation of interface segregation principle.

Let me show an example. For example, you have a HDD. And your interface would look like this:

```
public interface IHDD
{
    void Write();

    string Read();
}
```

then your `HDD` class would look like this:

```
public class HDD : IHDD
{
    public string Read()
    {
        return "So far so good!";
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some info has been written");
    }
}
```

In a few month, one person decides to implement `CardReader`. But we know that `CardReader` can just read, not write so `Write()` is decided to return `null` or even worth some exception:

```
public class CardReader : IHDD
{
    public string Read()
    {
        return "So far so good!";
    }

    public string Write()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Solution would be just to segregate this interface into two interfaces:

```
public interface IWriteable
{
    string Write();
}

public interface IReadable
{
    string Read();
}
```

And then your classes would look like this:

```
public class HDD : IWriteable, IReadable
{
    public string Read()
    {
        return "So far so good!";
    }

    public string Write()
    {
        return "Some info has been written";
    }
}

public class CardReader : IReadable
{
    public string Read()
    {
        return "So far so good!";
    }
}
```